# woocommerce error "There was an error processing your order - Field format error: Request is too large to process"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i m using **woocommerce**

getting error :

> There was an error processing your order - Field format error: Request
>   is too large to process

Comment: Please, read the guides [ask] and [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to improve your Question. As for the error: open all the plugin code and search for this error message.

Answer (score 0):

Having this same issue, seems to be related to having "too many" items in a cart, though too many could be as few as 7.

http://support.woothemes.com/entries/28939606-Field-format-error-Request-is-too-large-to-process